# Not able to click on a button on Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click on the Flight button on this flight website https://www.expedia.com/, but i do not know how. Tried to find the id on Inspect but couldn't. How can I click on the Flight Button on PyCharm.

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")

driver.maximize_window()  
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("Flights").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flights attribute doesn't have class name as `Flights`. It has text `Flights`

**HTML**:

```
<span class="uitk-tab-text">Flights</span>
```

**Code**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Flights']").click()
```

Always check your `xPath` in chrome console to make sure it is unique.

- Press `F12` in Chrome.
- Go to `elements` section
- Search ( `CTRL + F`)
- Place the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node. This means, your `xPath` is unique.

Comment: Why not to offer optional _css-selectors_ as well?

Comment: @DebanjanB Please correct me if I am wrong. At the end all the elements will be converted into `CSS` and the HTML tag has the class name that shared by other tags as well. So I used `text()` method. If there is any better way please let us know.

Comment: You are totally correct. For _css_ you can consider the `aria-controls` attribute of the parent `<a>` tag and then the descendent `<span>`

Comment: Surprised to find out another Selenium contributor who keeps track and at the same time have a deep understanding about what happens under the hood.

Comment: I learnt from your answers. The way you analyse the error trace provided by the OP and instead of fixing problems you explains them the reason as well :)